# Running and downloading App made by Unity by QR Code scanning

Tags: unity-game-engine, hyperlink, qr-code

I want to launch an App which is made by unity on Google play store.

But I heard that user can run and download with just one QRCode.

Case 1.

When user doesn't have the app.

In case user scan the QR Code, then play store need to be come up so that they can download it.

Case 2.

When user has the app.
then the app which has been installed comes up straight away without connecting Google Play Store.